# Java oop getters/setters within a class with deep copy

Tags: java, oop

We use java OOP with getters and setters within the class to use the logic inside the getters and setters within those access methods (even if there is no logic inside these methods).

Now, when we use getters/setters we don't return or work on the object reference we use a copy of it, for immutability purposes.

For example:

We have 2 classes, class A and class B:

```java
public class A {
    private int num;

    public A(int num) {
        this.changeNum(num);
    }

    public A(A other) {
        this(other.num());
    }

    public void changeNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int num() {
        return this.num;
    }

    public int multiply(int multiply) {
        return this.num() * multiply;
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class B {
    private List<A> list;

    public B(List<A> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void changeList(List<A> list) {
        this.list = copyList(list);
    }

    public List<A> list() {
        return copyList(this.list);
    }

    public int sumMultiply(int multiply) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (A a : this.list()) {
            sum += a.multiply(multiply);
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private static List<A> copyList(List<A> list) {
        List<A> copyList = new ArrayList<A>();

        for (A a : list) {
            copyList.add(new A(a));
        }

        return copyList;
    }
}
```

As we can see here, for a simple method that sums the multiplication of a list of objects, we need to do a deep copy.
so every access on the data members we need to make a deep copy.

Is there a better way to do this, or do we need to pick one approach:

- use copy/deep copy on getters and setters and access directly with this without access methods within the class
- access data members within a class with getters/setters without deep copy.

Comment: So are you asking if there is a way to have mutability, but not doing deep copy? what is the problem with deep copy? the time it takes?

Comment: @NathanHughes the object is mutable, but the field `List<A> list` in `B` should resemble an immutable list, but when you get it, you can edit it without affecting the original list.

Comment: I would first make `A` completely immutable by having `num` be `final`. This lets us avoid duplicating `A` each time. Next, I would modify `B` to not clone the list on read and instead copy the values to an private collection on write. Since the inner list can already be switched out for another at any time, it may be better to keep a single final list which stores our elements separately from the list they were passed with and can be updated each time the elements are changed. Or even better, we could make `B` completely immutable as well to match the style of `A`.

Comment: This way to clone objects on every getter seems incredibly overkill and will destroy performance for sure. The correct way to do this is through immutability: clone the objects only when necessary. Lombok can do most of the code automatically for you with `@Value`, `@Builder` and `@With`. Now, not everyone is a fan of Lombok.